# 2 checkboxes and when I uncheck one, I want the other to be checked

Tags: jquery

I sort of have it working but it only works once. I check the first box and then uncheck it and the other box checks but then when I check and uncheck the first one again,it doesn't work.

This will basically be like a radio button but the second checkbox will be hidden so they will just need to check or uncheck the first box.

Here is my code:

```js
$('input').on('change', function() {
  $(this).siblings().attr('checked', false);
  if ($(this).prop('checked') == false) {
    $(this).siblings().attr('checked', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in your case is that you're using the `.attr()` method to change the `checked` attribute of the sibling checkbox elements. Since you're changing the attribute, it will only work once. If you change it to `.prop()`, it should work as expected.

An easier approach would be to toggle the `checked` property of the sibling elements based on whether the current checkbox is checked. You could simply use `!this.checked` in your case:

```js
$('input').on('change', function() {
  $(this).siblings().prop('checked', !this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  Nothing like over-complicating things.